# R Overwrite column values with non NA values from column in separate dataframe

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have a dataframe 'df1' with a lot of columns, but the ones of interest are:

| Number | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 10 |  |
| 11 | AMRO |
| 4 |  |
| 277 |  |
| 2100 | BLPH |

And I have another dataframe 'df2' with a lot of columns, but the ones of interest are:

| Number | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AMCR |
| 2 | AMCR |
| 3 | BANO |
| 10 | BAEA |
| 12 | AMRO |
| 4 | NA |
| 277 | NA |
| 2100 | NA |

I want matching values in the 'Number' columns of 'df1' and 'df2' to lead to values in the 'Code' column in 'df2' to overwrite the 'Code' values in 'df1' as long as the 'Code' values in 'df2' don't contain an NA, so that the final result of 'df1' looks like:

| Number | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AMCR |
| 2 | AMCR |
| 3 | BANO |
| 10 | BAEA |
| 11 | AMRO |
| 4 |  |
| 277 |  |
| 2100 | BLPH |

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "Number", conflict = coalesce)
```

-output

```
Number Code
1      1 AMCR
2      2 AMCR
3      3 BANO
4     10 BAEA
5     11 AMRO
6      4 <NA>
7    277 <NA>
8   2100 BLPH
```

---

Or to do an overwrite, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, Code := fcoalesce(Code, i.Code), on = .(Number)]
```

-output

```
> df1
   Number   Code
    <int> <char>
1:      1   AMCR
2:      2   AMCR
3:      3   BANO
4:     10   BAEA
5:     11   AMRO
6:      4   <NA>
7:    277   <NA>
8:   2100   BLPH
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 277L, 2100L
), Code = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "AMRO", NA, NA, "BLPH")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df2 <- structure(list(Number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 12L, 4L, 277L, 2100L
), Code = c("AMCR", "AMCR", "BANO", "BAEA", "AMRO", NA, NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this method, but only overwrite values instead of doing a join. I think this method works just fine (I still need to double check), but what if both dataframes don't have the same columns and same number of columns?

Comment: @Jacob You could use `rows_upsert/rows_update` etc which depends on the data you have

Comment: Does this mean use those functions instead of power_left_join or in conjunction?

Comment: @Jacob I checked with `rows_upsert`, which does add more rows, which may not be desired.  But, I think an easier option is to update (`:=`) with `data.table` join as this will only update the desired columns and not create any extra `.x`, `.y` columns in the data while joining.  In the devel version of dplyr, there is also `join_by`

Comment: I like your thinking. I ran your new code and the Code column in df1 didn't get updated with anything. Looks like maybe nothing changed. What does the i.Code mean?

Comment: @Jacob That is unusual because `:=` does update in place.   The `i.` is used to differentiate common columns from the df1, df2 i.e. we specify i. for the one joined to df2

Comment: Yeah, it's not updating df1 with any new information. I think you have the correct answer here, but I need to play around with it more. Thank you for your continued help. It's always very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jacob  Try on a new R session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249994/discussion-between-jacob-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `bind_cols`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(Code = coalesce(Code...2, Code...4)) %>% 
  select(Number = Number...1, Code)
```

```
 Number Code
1      1 AMCR
2      2 AMCR
3      3 BANO
4     10 BAEA
5     11 AMRO
6      4 <NA>
7    277 <NA>
8   2100 BLPH
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for dataframes of differing lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution playing with `dplyr` `full_join` and `inner_join`

```r
library(dplyr)
```

```r
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2) %>% na.omit() %>% 
  full_join(df1 %>% inner_join(df2)) %>% 
  filter(Number %in% df1$Number) %>%
  arrange(Number)
```

#### Output

```r
#>   Number Code
#> 1      1 AMCR
#> 2      2 AMCR
#> 3      3 BANO
#> 4      4 <NA>
#> 5     10 BAEA
#> 6     11 AMRO
#> 7    277 <NA>
#> 8   2100 BLPH
```

Comment: I don't think this works. It seems to reduce the size of df1 to the number of rows that match with df2. I want df1 to remain as it is, except with updated values in the Code column.

Comment: I've edited now adding `filter()`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is still reducing the length of df1 to only those rows that match df2. I want all other rows in df1 left as they were. Thank you for your efforts on this though!

Comment: The output I've provided in this response match the expected output provided in your question. The only difference is that `Number` here is a numeric variable, so it is order numerically, while your output is ordered alphabetically by `Number`.